# Notification when user uninstalls IPhone app

Tags: ios

Is there any way to get a notification when the user uninstalls my networked IPhone app, preferably including some custom data from the app's preferences like the user ID?

What I'm trying to do is to automatically delete the user's data from the server backend when they delete the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing like this is the [feedback service](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3) of Apple Push Notifications. So, if you're using push notifications and you can readily recreate the user's data if they reinstall the app, you can use the feedback service as a trigger mechanism for cleaning up your user database. Just make sure that all devices associated with the user record have deleted the app before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have only approach - it is to set user data expiration time.
Check last user activity time using:

1. Push Notification Sending error (see @warrenm post)
2. or time when user had access to your services
3. or use log services like BugSence or TestFlight to do the same